# SwiftUI view doesn't react to array property changing

Tags: swift, swiftui, reactive

Showing a list of MessageView:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ConversationViewModel = ConversationViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(viewModel.messages, id: \.id) { m in
            MessageView(message: m)
                .id(m.id)
        }
    }
```

Provided by the viewModel:

```
class ConversationViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var messages: [Message] = []
}
```

The Message struct:

```
struct Message: Identifiable, Equatable {
    var id = UUID()
    var type: MessageType = .text
    var author: MessageAuthor
    var body: String = ""
    var timestamp: Date = Date()
    var failed: Bool = false
    var media: URL?
    var isLast: Bool = false
    
    static func == (lhs: Message, rhs: Message) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}
```

And then the MessageView being shown for each message:

```
struct MessageView: View {
    private let message: Message
    
    init(message: Message) {
        self.message = message
    }

    var body: some View {
    if message.type == .image {
                if (message.media != nil) {
                    AsyncImage(url: message.media)
                } else {
                    Text("No media.")
                }
    }
```

Even once the viewModel makes the message.media take a value instead of being null, the above MessageView always shows "No media.".

The viewModel publishes the messages array, and Message is a struct... I think I'm doing everything right, but I'm obviously missing something here.

Any ideas?

Comment: Because of this line `.id(m.id)` so you need to change the id of your message when change its data. Actually you don't need it. Watch this wwdc https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/

Answer (score 0):

try this approach, changing the logic of your `MessageView` and
using `@StateObject var viewModel = ConversationViewModel()` in `ContentView`. And as mentioned, remove `static func == ...`.
Works well for me.

```
 struct MessageView: View {
     let message: Message  // <-- here
     
     var body: some View {
         if message.type == .image {
             if (message.media != nil) {
                 AsyncImage(url: message.media)
             } else {
                 Text("No image")
             }
         } else {
             Text("case text presumably")  // <-- here
         }
     }
 }
```

You could also use a `switch` instead of `if/else`.